# Limit Number of Weeks to be in a certain range

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to limit a number of weeks to be within the range of 4 to 12 weeks.
Currently, I am doing the following:

```
var weeksBetween = todaysDate.diff(startDate, 'weeks');
```

Is there a simple way to check if `weeksBetween` is between the range of 4 and 12. And if not, return 4 (below) or 12 (above)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use a simple `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper function for what you are trying to do not to copy-paste the same logic everywhere

```
function weekDiff(date) {
  var MIN_WEEKS = 4;
  var MAX_WEEKS = 12;

  var weeksBetween = moment().diff(date, 'weeks');

  return Math.min(Math.max(weeksBetween, MIN_WEEKS), MAX_WEEKS);
}
```

Also here [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kk6fp5sg/1/)

Comment: Since i didn't want to use an if statement, this solution is exactly what I was looking work. Worked like a charm! Thanks!